# Changing open graph image tag based on blog post item

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am maintaining a wordpress blog and am familiar with using the og:image meta tag to set the default image that is included when a like button is pressed. What I want to know is if there is a way to make this image dynamic based on the item liked.

I am trying to build it so that the first image in a particular blog post that is liked is what is pushed to the facebook feed post, with the blog's default image only used if there is no image in the post. Does facebook provide any way to do this with the graph api?

I tried writing javascript to change the meta tag on article pages (rather than the homepage) but found out later the crawler does not run javascript, so am now considering implementing the same but server side with PHP. This still would not solve the problem of Likes from the blog homepage, where there are multiple blog items on the page though. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only is changing how the meta tags get rendered to the client, in server code or in your layout template.  There is no graph api method for this and you can't modify the tags with javascript as their scraper doesn't execute javascript.

Also, the scraper won't keep re-visiting your site so once it access it, it will be cached until you go to the url linter tool manually.   so for the home page, you would probably just want the default image.